# How to save the DIV element as jpg or bmp file?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have a webpage where on div (a square box) which will be used to drag and drop image icons write some text change background color , I want to make that div after dropping elements saved as jpg, bmp format.

Can somebody help me how to do it, using ASP.net C#?

i tried and used canvas but that doesn't work, it only save the div (square box) with white background.

Comment: look at it :) http://forums.asp.net/t/1917875.aspx/1

Comment: its something different i am looking for a postion of html to be saved as image @MichaelUnterthurner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `canvas`?

One link worth thousand words.
[Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Comment: thanks grmmph yes but the problem is it does not work on IE.. can other solution?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/    -> Excanvas is a alternative - a JS library that simulates the canvas element using IE's VML renderer.

Comment: canvas is not helping as when i am trying to save as image.. it become blank white box.. whatever is drag and drop on that box always go..